# $\binom{2.10^n}{10^n}$ is divisible by 10 but not by 100

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

$\binom{2.10^n}{10^n}$ is divisible by 10 but not by 100 $\forall n\geq 2$
I know that $\binom{2n}{n}$ is divisible by $n+1$.
But i am nowhere near the given problem.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: This is false for $n=0$ and $n=1$.

Comment: True for 2 and 3.

Comment: It is also false when $n=5$ and $n=8$, which can by computing $\binom{2\cdot 10^n}{10^n}$ modulo $2$ and $5$ using Lucas's theorem. I have checked it is true for all $n\ge 9$, up to $n=2500$.

Comment: @MikeEarnest do you have any idea,how this kind of problem can be tackled?

Answer (score 0):

The highest exponent of $5$ that divides $c\cdot10^n$ where integer $c\le4$

will be $$f(c)=2c(1+10+\cdots+10^{n-1}=\dfrac{2c(10^n-1)}{10-1}$$

The denominator $=f^2(1)$

What about the numerator?

Comment: what  are trying to say?it's not clear to me.And,by $f^2(1)$ you mean $(f(1))^2$ or $f(f(1)).$?